# How to ensure that static resources created by me in my sandbox are pulled to my local IDE (IntelliJ)

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, static-resources, illuminatedcloud

I tried to pull the static resources using Illuminated cloud as well as through sfdx commands, but can not see the static resources created by me in the static resources folder (in the local IDE)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Illuminated cloud` for this, then you have to first refresh the metadata.

Go to configure module and click `Refresh`.

[image]

You should be able to see the newly created static resource in your org under `Static Resource` section. -> Select all.

Then from your project base folder -> Select `Retrieve Metadata`.

Here you will be able to see the new static resource now. And can retrieve it.